# Windows permissions : TRUSTEE_TYPE

Tags: windows, winapi, file-permissions, win32-process

At my workplace, we incorporating the Windows DACL permissions model in our app and we aim to find the permissions of files/folders using the Windows permissions APIs.

While going through the documentation of [TRUSTEE_TYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/accctrl/ne-accctrl-_trustee_type), we realized that for us, TRUSTEE_TYPE will always be `TRUSTEE_IS_USER` as our app will be always launched by the logged-in user.

But I wanted to understand more about remaining `TRUSTEE_TYPE`s. 
Specifically

```
  TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP,
  TRUSTEE_IS_DOMAIN,
  TRUSTEE_IS_ALIAS,
  TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP,
  TRUSTEE_IS_COMPUTER
```

When does these other types come into the picture?

That is , given a program/an app process , how does group/domain/alias/well_known_group/computer becomes its `TRUSTEE_TYPE` ? 
If so, who does it ?

Put it another way, in what situations does the `TRUSTEE_IS_USER` is not set and is set to other types mentioned above ?

================================================

***Update***

Use case details:

We are implementing a capability to fetch/modify permissions for files/folders by using dacl interface APIs such as GetFileSecurity and so on.

We convert these permissions to our internal custom bit masks such as user_read , group_read and domain_read so that this interface is easily adopted by other developers.

But reading the theory on trustee types and dacl permissions model, we realize that trustee type is set at the time when process is launched by a logged in user/owner (this is almost always true).

We are ,sort of trying to create a one to one mapping between trustee types(with windows generic permissions) and our custom permissions bit marks.

Our app will almost always be launched by a logged in user and hence while querying windows permissions api, we set the trustee type as user.

Now we are trying understand if (at all or ever) this trustee type would have to be group/domain/alias/well_known_group/computer as we are creating our custom bit masks for each of them which seems wasteful given that our trustee would always be a user.

Hence the question.

Comment: The `DACL` may contain entries with the types that you list. And of course your user can be in a group or in a well known group, so `TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP` and `TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP` would be relevant. Regarding the rest of your question you should better describe what you want to achieve and where you fail to do so. For example it is not clear to me what exactly you assume when you write that for your app `TRUSTEE_TYPE` will always be `TRUSTEE_IS_USER`.

Comment: @Werner Henze .... Question updated.

Comment: What comes to my mind: you probably need to be able to convert file ACLs containing a group trustee to your representation because you cannot guarantee that only your app is used for changing file permissions.